# Mailchimp 3.0 API subscribing address multiple times doesn't return error

Tags: php, angularjs, curl, mailchimp

I'm trying to subscribe users to a Mailchimp list.

I'm using Angular on the frontend, but the data all gets sent to PHP to do the http request with curl.

I have removed all of the frontend code for this test and I am just sticking with the PHP.

I'm testing all of this locally with MAMP. In initial tests, attempting to subscribe the same email address would throw an error, as it should according to the Mailchimp 3.0 API reference:

> You’ll receive errors if the address is already on your list, or if any required merge_fields are missing. [http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/](http://reference)

Unfortunately, this isn't happening now, and I'm able to subscribe the same email address multiple times with the code below.  I've confirmed this in the response as well as the Mailchimp list admin.

```
function mailchimp_signup(){
    $data = $this->input->post();

    $data = array(
                'email_address' => 'testaccount@test.com',
                'status' => 'subscribed',
                'merge_fields' => array(
                        'FNAME' => 'Chester',
                        'LNAME' => 'Copperpot'
                    )
                );

    $data_json = json_encode($data);

    $url = 'https://XXX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/XXXXXXXXX/members/';

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "auth:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data_json);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json)));   
    $response  = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
    echo $response;
}
```

I'm still logging the entire response via my Angular service and controller, and I'm able to submit the same email address multiple times with POST  and change the merge field data, which, of course, is not ideal.

I'm wondering if there's something I'm doing here that is causing me not to get the default behavior that I originally saw. Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: The code you posted works okay for me and I get an error on subsequent calls, although I know MailChimp had a few bugs make their way out a few weeks ago and they've been slowly getting fixed since; are you still seeing this behavior?

Comment: Thanks so much for checking this out @TooMuchPete.  It was driving me crazy.  I didn't change any of the code and now it seems it's working correctly now.  This akes me think I want to run my own check on subscriber status first though.

Comment: You'll definitely want to catch errors, but you should also look into PUT which updates if the record already exists. Doing an extra call to check status could be fine, but is extra overhead you probably don't need.